# Arch linux : pacman does not work when chrooting

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, proc, pacman

I have Ubuntu installed on my computer. I decided to install Arch linux, but I skipped the part about Grub installation as it is already installed. Seeing that Arch does not show up in Grub's menu list, I decided to install it in Arch. I mounted Arch's partition in Ubuntu and I chrooted into it. I issued the command `pacman -S grub-bios` and got the following :

```
error: could not open file: /etc/mtab: No such file or directory
error: could not determine filesystem mount points
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

`/etc/mtab` is a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`, but there is nothing in the `/proc` folder.

What am I doing wrong?

As a complement, am I going in the right direction to make Arch appear in Grub's list? **EDIT** : I was able to make Arch appear in Grub's list from Ubuntu by doing `sudo mount /dev/sdaX` (*replace X with Arch's partition number*) before `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Did you mount `{/proc,/sys/,/dev}` as per the [wiki entry for chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot#Mount_the_partitions)?

Comment: Yes, I now get a series of errors like this : `error: failed retrieving file 'grub-bios-2.00-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.cinosure.com : Could not resolve host: (nil); Unknown error`

Comment: But shouldn't my Arch partition be independent from the others?

Comment: Did you copy `/etc/resolv.conf` into the chroot? Otherwise the chrooted programs don't know your DNS settings.

Comment: Try updating your package database: `pacman -Sy`. You may also want to try generating a new mirror list.

Comment: I tried that without success. I turned off my router and turned it back on and I could access Internet again. I don't know what was the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remember to `arch-chroot` and not simply `chroot` - that way `/proc` will be populated and pacman will function as expected.

Comment: I've edited it slightly so that it doesn't sound like a comment and removed the flag :-)

Comment: Right, thank you. I'm still not entirely used to the conventions on this site :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have IPv6 enabled? I'm unable to use pacman with IPv6 enabled on any of my machines. You should try to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Per OP's edit, he got Arch to appear in GRUB by manually mounting his Arch partition and then rerunning `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. What I did wrong was just changing root, without checking the wiki entry for [chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Chroot#Using_chroot) and thus not mounting the temporary filesystems required. Following the guide did the trick. Who'd have guessed? haha